# What is the difference between Backbone's view.remove() method and using $(div).html('')

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have seen examples of managing backbone views and events attached to them in a single page architecture, where you can use `view.remove();` for the current view and call the next view using require.js syntax, whenever you navigate to a different view. But can this be also achieved by simply emptying the html of the current view using `$(div).html('');`? Are both approaches going to have the same result? What are the differences, if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple difference is

**.remove()**

> Removes a view from the DOM, and calls stopListening to remove any
>   bound events that the view has listenTo'd.

If your view has these 2 listeners in the initialize.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

Your vies is listening to the model and the collection. So if you use `remove` to get rid of the view it will unbind the events for the view.

Where as if you do `$('div').html()` there is still a reference to the view and the methods on the view are still present in the memory along with the listeners which will cause **memory leaks** in your application. This is just one of the difference and there might be many more.

Comment: So if i haven't used `listenTo` but just click events mentioned in the `events` block of the view, then that too won't be unbound if i use `$('div').html('')` ? Also, what if i use `view.unbind()` or `view.off()`. That way the event listeners are unbound but i think, as you said, the view and its methods still remain in memory. Right?

Comment: @RahulDole.. right. you are just removing the elements but the zombie events are still present and the view items persist in the memory.

Comment: Great.. understood completely. i can see how important and inevitable it is to use `view.remove()`
Thanks sushanth

Comment: @RahulDole.. Glad to have helped :)